# Blazor two-way binding on a child component with a default value

Tags: razor, blazor, 2-way-object-databinding

Given a Child component:

```
<p>Name: @Name</p>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Scooby Do";
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> NameChanged { get; set; }
}
```

And a Parent component with two-way binding on the `Name` property:

```
Name: <InputText @bind-Value=@Name/>
<ChildComponent @bind-Name=@Name />

@code {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

It appears the `ChildComponent.Name` is overwritten by the null value from the `ParentComponent.Name` property.

I would like the value "Scooby Do" from the Child to be bound up to the Parent as the default value.

How do I enable the two-way binding but use the Child component's default values?

Answer (score 1):

To apply the default rule once, add this to the Child:

```
[Parameter]
public string Name { get; set; } // = "Scooby Do";  
... 

protected override async Task  OnInitializedAsync()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) )
    {
        await NameChanged.InvokeAsync("Scooby Do");
    }
}
```

when you want to replace it with "Scooby Do" again when the user empties the textbox then override  OnParametersSetAsync instead, with the same code.